# Strange memory behaviour with static initializer of AVQueuePlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have declared property

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) AVQueuePlayer *player;
```

and when I initialize it with `+ queuePlayerWithItems:` it is not deallocated if I assign to `player` new object or nil. Even if I do it right after one row below. When I initialize `player` with `– initWithItems:` everything works as expected. I use ARC. Is it bug or are not static initializers autoreleasing or what is the difference? I remember the times before ARC when it would be like

```
+ (AVQueuePlayer *)queuePlayerWithItems:(NSArray *)items
{
    return [[[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:items] autorelease];
}
```

So what is the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ARC your code may like look as this:

```
+ (AVQueuePlayer *)queuePlayerWithItems:(NSArray *)items 
{
    return [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:items];
}
```

The compiler *may* still put the created object into an autorelease pool, though. Whether or not this happens also depends on the level of optimization set, and whether the [method family](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#method-families) is correctly recognized.

You can help the compiler declaring the method like this:

```
+ (AVQueuePlayer *)queuePlayerWithItems:(NSArray *)items NS_RETURNS_RETAINED;
```

This will cause the compiler to assume that the method returns an allocated object and needs to be sent a balanced `release` message when appropriate, instead to put the object into the autorelease pool.

`NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` will expand to `__attribute__((ns_returns_retained))`

The definition should omit the attribute `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED`.

#### Edit:

If this is not your method and if you cannot change the declaration, you may use an explicit autorelease pool to get rid of the autoreleased object:

```
{
    AVQueuePlayer* player;
    @autoreleasepool {
       // the next line retains the returned object:
       player = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:items];
    }  // here, the autorelease pool releases the returned object (it's still alive)
    // do something with variable player:
    ...
    [player ...];  // last usage of variable player
    // now, the last reference to player ceases to exist, it gets released and deallocated

}
```

Comment: But `+ queuePlayerWithItems:` is not mine. It's in Apple API. Should I avoid using it? Why? Because of wrong optimization? I so much hate when I don't understand things...

Comment: @user620297 It's better to understand the issue: if the newly created object is put into the autorelease pool, it won't be deallocated until after the program leaves the scope of this autorelease pool (and if this was the last strong reference). Perhaps an explicit autorelease pool will help to get rid of the object. See my edit.

Comment: But this is property I have problem with. You know... I set it, then set it again (with new instance or nil), and previous set object was not deallocated. The most strange think is, that is properly deallocated if it is initialized with `– initWithItems:`.

Comment: The factory method `queuePlayerWithItems:` returns an "autoreleased" object. This object will be _eventually_ deallocated when the autorelease pool gets drained. Before ARC we had not to call `release`. In contrast, the object returned from `initWithItems:`is not put into the autorelease pool. Before ARC we had to call `release` in order to keep the retain count balanced. Now, in ARC in both cases you don't need to worry. However, you may experience exactly what you observe.